# Watching a $locationProvider in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, window.location

I need to watch changes on the URL bar and do certain actions based on that. I wondered what's the best way to add a watch to view changes to it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Events exist, they're just undocumented for some reason.

Try the following events: `$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess`

```
scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newLoc, oldLoc){
   console.log('changing to: ' + newLoc);
});

scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, newLoc, oldLoc){
   console.log('changed to: ' + newLoc);
});
```

Or you can $watch any value you want by passing a function into the $watch's first argument as Anders suggested:

```
scope.$watch(function() { return $location.path(); }, function(newLoc, oldLoc){
   console.log(newLoc, oldLoc);
});
```

However this will create a little more overhead on your $digest.

Comment: Thanks @blesh. trying to identify when the two events are emitted and whats the difference between them. any ideas?

Comment: It's all set up in the initialization code for $location. [Have a look at the source on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js). Just CTRL+F for $locationChangeStart.  It's basically the same as the $watch() method suggested, but it's already set up for you, so there's less overhead.

Comment: In a nutshell,  `$locationChangeStart` happens first and gives you an option to prevent the change with `preventDefault()` on the event object passed to it.  `$locationChangeSuccess` fires after the location is successfully changed. (rather, when you've committed to changing the location).

Comment: so we should consider $locationChangeStart and $locationChangeSuccess to have a before and after relationship to a route?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have requested the $location object in your controller, you can do it like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return $location.path() }, function() {
    // Do stuff when the location changes
});
```